Finding detailed info about QGIS Expressions
I am using QGIS Expressions for showing images in DISPLAY hints:
After some trail and error the following works:
<img src= "file:///[% @project_folder || to_string('/BILDER/') || "BILD" %]">
where BILDER is the folder with the images and BILD is the field in the attribute-table, which contains the image-names like pic1.png.
I did look at the official documentation: https://docs.qgis.org/3.34/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/expression.html but I could not find
any information about:
A)  file:/// , why do I have to use it in the html-image-tag in QGIS? In any html-browser (e.g. Chrome) the source-tag has no file-part, eg:  
B) Why do I have sometimes to use [%     %]  for enclosing QGIS-Expressions?
C) @expression : the @ seems to be necessary for identifying "variables", which can have different values like the "variable" @project-folder. Is this true?

A) see File URI scheme
B) see 16.1.13. Display Properties and 22.2.4. The Label Item
C) see 13.2.27. Variables
